# Parse terminal prompt and enter input programmatically

Tags: python, bash, terminal

In my Python script, I have the following bash prompt from an API call:

```
URL: http://urlhere.com/aBcDeFg (URL always different)
Input: << (able to enter input here)
```

The URL has information required to fulfill the input correctly.

Since the Python script is interrupted, I'd like to be able to process the URL, perhaps by spawning a child process. The child process would open the URL, grab the data needed, then be able to enter input programmatically with data from the processed URL.

The code:

```
setup.retrieve_url()   // this will generate the URL prompt
print "hello"   // never reached until prompt is fulfilled.
```

Any pointers on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why does this need to be in another child process?.. Do you have your current code you can share?

Comment: The code is simple. The script pauses at the function call and does not continue until the prompt is fulfilled. I'm thinking I need another script to parse the URL from the Terminal?

Comment: Please explain "bash prompt from an API all" because it is not clear what you are actually talking about. Are you calling the API from your code? Are you calling a shell script, and then you need to send it some input? What?

Comment: In the code, setup.retrieve_url() is a library function that is abstracted away. It returns a prompt with the URL and a request for input that I need to enter correctly to continue. Please let me know if that makes more sense

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to use [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) to spawn and control your Python script.